# I have designed a Graph for my ASP.NET WEbsite. It has compatibility issues, suggestions required

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, canvas, cross-browser

I have a rgraph in my website, I use the rgraph http://www.rgraph.net/docs/index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/RGraph.vprogress.js"></script>
 <!--[if IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/excanvas.original.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

[No canvas support]
                [No canvas support]

It works fine in IE 8 but when i turn the Compatibility view on for the IE 8 then I get this error

```
Line: 30
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Note from rgraph website:
Since the charts are produced using HTML5 features (the new canvas tag), client support is currently:
Microsoft Internet Explorer 8+

Is there any method or way to make in work in compatibility view. Or an graph which work work perfectly in all browsers. I want to draw a bar and a pie chart. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what line 30 is, but, if it is related to the canvas, then try
[this alternative](http://onepixelahead.com/2010/05/12/how-to-use-html5-canvas-with-ie6-ie7-and-ie8/). Include it conditionally on platforms where canvas is not available, IE7 and maybe IE8.